# Usage of an article when one adjective modifies two nouns

Tags: articles, modifiers

I want to say 'a specific method' and 'a specific parameter'.

I actually want to express

> I use a general method that can be determined by the operator instead of a specific annealing algorithm, and I use a general parameter that can be determined by the operator instead of a specific value.

When I combine these two sentenses,

> I use general method and parameter that can be determined by the operator instead of specific annealing algorithm and value.

I thought that "noun and noun" is not singular but plural, so I omit an article "a". Is it correct? Also, I am wondering if readers can misunderstand that "general" modifies only "method" or both "method" and "parameter". Is there any good sentence composition?

Comment: I'd leave it in the original form. The attempted deletion is neither idiomatic nor clear.